# How can make a program so as to get Search Results in another Window

Tags: javascript

I am udemy learner of javascript and In one the recent classes I learnt how to format url string the using javacscript.

Now I want to make a program in which user enters the string (say - harry potter) in form text input field and then on clicking button it redirects  to second page and display that string search in BING  search engine.

I tried to write some code but I failed. Can anybody help me ??

Following are the files I made

pastebin.com/syCzrqEe
pastebin.com/AgvCgCif

Comment: Post the code you got so that we can show you where you want astray

Comment: Show your code and underline the problem that you have.

Comment: @binskits  there are two files I am trying to make in but I failed. I was doing manipulations to the following files   https://pastebin.com/syCzrqEe  and https://pastebin.com/AgvCgCif  . I tried to change some of the lines but I sucked. Sorry, though these files might be of basic level to you guys but I am struggling as I am beginner

Answer (score 1):

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="myinput">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
  document.forms[0].onsubmit = function() {
    var query = document.getElementById('myinput').value;
    window.open('http://www.bing.com/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query));
    return false;
  }
</script>
```